# vim-latex/latex-suite: command sequences not coloured

Tags: colorscheme

Some command sequences consisting of `\` and a non-letter (`,`, `2`) are not coloured (`\&` is). How to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe to signal that your macro/command would be [invalid](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-linmacnames.html)?

I'm not saying it's the right way, just what's the idea.

Vim TeX statements (part of the `texCmdGroup`), from `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/tex.vim`:

```
" TeX/LaTeX keywords: {{{1
" Instead of trying to be All Knowing, I just match \..alphameric..
" Note that *.tex files may not have "@" in their \commands
if exists("g:tex_tex") || b:tex_stylish
  syn match texStatement    "\\[a-zA-Z@]\+"
else
  syn match texStatement    "\\\a\+"
  if !exists("s:tex_no_error") || !s:tex_no_error
   syn match texError       "\\\a*@[a-zA-Z@]*"
  endif
endif
```

In addition, recognized special chars are:

```
syn match texSpecialChar    "\\[$&%#{}_]"
```

You can add a syntax rule for the `texStatement` in `~/.vim/after/syntax/tex.vim`: e.g. `syn match texStatement "\\[0-9 ,;\\]"`.

Comment: But it would not? `\,` and `\3` are perfectly valid command sequence names.

Comment: Edited with some digging.

Comment: I tried but it didn’t work. I don’t think I have the file you cited. Are you using vim-latex/latex-suite?

Comment: No, you'l have to create the `.../after/syntax/tex.vim` file yourself (see for example http://usevim.com/2012/03/07/syntax-highlighting/ )

Comment: Better: `syn match texStatement "\\[^a-zA-Z]"`.